# annotation Display Priority doesn't do what I expect, how to keep custom pin on screen

Tags: swift, mapkit, mkmapview, mkannotation

I use the code below on view did load to add a custom annotation icon for the map center that the user started at so that if they scroll away they can always see their starting point.

```
    if let lat = curBlip.blip_lat, let lon = curBlip.blip_lon {
        let mapCenter = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lon)
        let mapSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)
        let mapRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(mapCenter, mapSpan)
        self.map.setRegion(mapRegion, animated: true)

        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = coordinate
        annotation.title = "Your Blips Location"
        annotation.subtitle = "Subtitle Placeholder"

        self.map.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

When the view loads I load that annotation so its always first and I set a bool named "set" to true after the first annotation to ensure that it gets the custom icon.  The issue I am having is that even though I have the annotation set to display priority required the annotation disappears when I move the map away.  How can I make that annotation always persist or is there a better way to set a "this is where the map started" circle that doesn't go away?

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if set {
        return nil
    } else {
        let view = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "annotationId")
        view.image = UIImage(named: "locationArea50")
        view.canShowCallout = true
        view.displayPriority = .required
        set = true
        return view
    }
```

[image: Blue circle annotation appears]

Then after I scroll the map away a little bit, I suspect scrolling far enough that the system has to make them reappear the annotation disappears.  I assume this has to do with how the grouping of annotations works but that blue annotation is special and I want it to always be present, which is what I thought displayPriority did.

[image]

Comment: Could you add an animated gif to show this "go away"?

Comment: I will work on getting screen shots (not sure how to screen capture phone into animated gif) but the series of events to make it disappear:  Map comes up.  I use my finger to scroll the map away from initial map region, and when I come back to the initial spot the nil annotations are there but "locationArea50" annotation is gone.  It also doesn't come back when I zoom in.  I suspect I did something wrong with "dequeing" or setting identifiers?

Comment: wild guess 1: are you sure you are adding this annotation in main thread?

Comment: wild guess 2: are you sure that your implementation of mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?  works correctly when called the second time for this type of annotation?

Comment: I added screen shots.  I also tested calling a second time by randomly having the 3rd annotation be the special one again and it added a second time.  I basically have one of my annotations that is the anchor point for all the other ones and I want it to always be present.

Comment: mapView is allowed to call `mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation)` multiple times for the same annotation. The first time you return an ˚MKAnnotationView˚, the second time you don't. So always return the ˚MKAnnotationView˚ and all should be good. (And don't name a variable ˚set˚)

Answer (score 0):

The default value of `displayPriority` is `.required` .
So for correct overlapping you need to downgrade priority of red annotations:

`redAnnotation.displayPriority = .defaultHigh`